# Change text of button is not working when used in ListView in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to change the text of button quickly after click on it. I am using here state to change the button text, but its not working when i clicked on it and that original text remains same.

where i am going wrong? help...

here is my code

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    button_text:"Connect",
  }
}

ConPressed() {
  this.setState({
    button_text: "Connected",
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.sa}
      renderRow={(rowData) => 

     <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.ConPressed()}>
        <Text>{this.state.button_text}</Text>
     </TouchableHighlight>

    />
  );
}
```

Comment: your code seems to be good, try checking that Conpressed() is triggered or not

Comment: @ManzoorSamad i knew my problem is what? I am using that button in `ListView` and hence its not working, other than than listview its working well but the problem is that Why the change of button_text i snot working in listview.

Comment: the row component for the list view is basically an another component, each component will maintain its own states, so check for any other issues